# How do I get product name for whatever product page I am on?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I have looked around and I swear all I can do is just get all product names to display.

For example if I am on product page x I want to show x's product name. So far I have the below code and it displays them all.

```
    <?php
     $_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');

     foreach ($_products as $product){
     $prod_name = $product->getData('name');
     echo $prod_name . '<br>';
     $attribute = $product->getData('attribute');

 }
    ?>
```

Comment: What page are you calling this code from? Some pages have the product already loaded, and to load it a second (or 20th) time would have serious impact on performance.

Comment: it was from the viewcart.phtml file

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

then

```
$product->getName();
$product->getId();
```

You can try this for product :

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$current_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

Comment: I've tried this but it does not seem to print anything out.

Comment: @Jake, are you using this on product view page ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get product name using product id.

```
$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product = $obj->load($product_id); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id
// get Product's name
echo $_product->getName();
```

Comment: I know i can do it like this but i want to get the product ID automatically

Comment: You can get it by using `getId()` method on product object.

Comment: doesn't work, i tried this  <?php
     $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $_product = $obj->getId(); 
        echo $_product->getName();
        ?>

Comment: `$product->getId();` will print the product id.

Answer (score 3):

```
  $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();        
  $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
  $path = $url->getPath();                                        
  $oRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
              ->loadByRequestPath(ltrim($path,'/'));              
  $pId = $oRewrite->getProductId();                             

   if($pId > 0)                                                               
    echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pId)->getName();
```

tested on magento 1.9.2.3 (was placed in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml file)

references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254789/magento-load-product-by-url 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192212/get-current-url-in-magento-and-show-something

Answer (score 2):

If you are already on the Product View page, then the Magento system already has loaded the product.

Look at the class: `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`

Then look at its function:

```
/**
 * Retrieve current product model
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    if (!Mage::registry('product') && $this->getProductId()) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
        Mage::register('product', $product);
    }
    return Mage::registry('product');
}
```

From there you are able to print various attributes from the product, such as code from the template file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php /* ... cut ... */ ?>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
    <div class="no-display">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="product-shop">
        <div class="product-name">
            <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this,hope it's help to you**.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product'); then
$product->getName();
$product->getId();
```

You can try this for product :

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$current_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```